# How to install react packages in runtime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, npm-install

I have several packages that need to be installed in my react project, however they require decent amount of disk space and I want to install them conditionally, so I won't install them before running the program, but they will be installed after user interacts with a specific component that requires those specific packages. Is there any way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Are you worried about the download size for the end users? Or is it really a problem on your disk?

Comment: I'm more worried about end users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm barely 100% percent this is not possible for the reason that your React code is probably bundled. When bundling, your bundler will try to resolve each imports and that means that your packages have to be installed.
BUT, i think the thing you need is simply `code-splitting`. If you're not familiar with this concept, it just split your main bundle into multiple bundles. Once a bundle is required (a huge component to load for example), your server will fetch this specific bundle, that means you don't have to deal with unnecessary huge loadings.